# Subtract addresses – Warning: “differs in levels of indirection”

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

Why do I receive a warning? `pch` is already the pointer I got and when I want to subtract the addresses I use `&Origi` for that.

> *C4047 '-' : 'char*' differs in levels of indirection from 'char (*)[12]'*

```
// Substring

    char Origi[] = { "Hallo Welt." };
    char* pch = strstr(Origi, "Welt"); // “pch” is a pointer that in this example points 6 characters further than the start of “Origi”.
    printf("%d\n", pch - &Origi);
    printf("%c\n", Origi[pch - &Origi]);
```

Comment: Weird error message in any case. `char*` and `char(*)[12]` definitely don't differ by level of indirection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the snippet:

```
printf("%d\n", pch - &Origi);
```

`Origi` is already of type `char*` because when you pass an array as argument it decays to a pointer to its first element, passing its address will make it a pointer to array of chars, which is not the same as a pointer to char and will cause a type mismatch in the binary operation.

For the pointer arithmetic to work properly the operands must be of the same type. It should be:

```
printf("%d\n", pch - Origi);

                |_____|____
                          |
                          ---> same type -> char*
```

For the second case it's much the same logic, `Origi` is already a pointer to `char`. It should be:

```
printf("%c\n", Origi[pch - Origi]);

                       |_____|____
                                 |
                                 ---> same type -> char*
```

I'll admit the error issued by msvc is not the best, it should be something like in gcc, for example, which is much more on point:

> *error: invalid operands to binary - (have 'char* *' and 'char* (*)[12]')*

Or better yet, in clang:

> *error: 'char* *' and 'char* (*)[12]' are not pointers to compatible types*